# Sign up / Login in swift 2.0 Error

Tags: swift

Not quite sure what i'm missing here to make this code work. Trying to make an app with login / sign up connecting to a server but i cant seem to get it to work. This is my code :

```
    do {

        let post:NSString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

        NSLog("PostData: %@",post)

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.ec2-54-191-63-219.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/userRegistration.php")!

        let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
            {data, response, error in

                do {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as? NSDictionary

                    if let parsejson = json
                    {
                        let resultValue:String = parsejson["status"] as! String

                        print("result: \(resultValue)")


                        if (resultValue == "Success")
                        {
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Registration Successful", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){action in self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)}

                            alert.addAction(okAction)

                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        print(resultValue)
                        }
                    }


                } catch {
                    print("failed: \(error)")
                }
        }

        task.resume()
```

this is the error i get when i try and add an account:

> ```
> PostData: username=Optional("josh")&password=Optional("test")
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all, you are derefencing a nil `data` value, likely `data` in the line `JSONObjectWithData(data!, ...`, but it should be obvious from where the debugger stops.  guard against the error, and go upstream from that.

```
if error != nil { handle error and abort }

... etc
```

Comment: thx used guard error == nil && data != nil else {print("error =\(error)"); return}, needed to update the url from when i restarted the server.